# Haskell duplicate element at certain position

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to duplicate the n-th elemnt of a list and my knowledge of haskell is very limited.
I tried splitting the list in two parts, then getting the last element of the first part and just pasting it between those parts:

```
dupl n (x:xs) = (take n (x:xs)) ++ ( (x:xs) !! n) ++ (drop n (x:xs))
```

But I always get the error:

```
Prelude> :l f.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( f.hs, interpreted )

f.hs:5:39:
   Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
   In the first argument of `(:)', namely `x'
   In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `(x : xs)'
   In the first argument of `(++)', namely `((x : xs) !! n)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list !! n` returns a list *element*, not a list. `++` can only concatenate *lists*; you can't add a list element to a list with `++`.

To put it more formally, `!!` has a type of:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

which means that it accepts a list of `a`s and an `Int`, and returns an `a`. `++`, on the other hand, has a type of:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

which means that it accepts two lists of `a`s and returns a new list of `a`s. So you can see that `++` accepts lists, but `!!` doesn't return lists, so you're not allowed to chain them together like that.

---

How do we fix this? You need to put the element `list !! n` into a list, in order to concatenate it to the other two lists without the type checker throwing a hissy fit.

This should do the trick:

```
dupl n l = (take n l) ++ [l !! n] ++ (drop n l)
```

---

Equivalently, add the chosen element to the right-hand list, and concatenate that to the other half of the original list:

```
dupl n l = (take n l) ++ ((l !! n):(drop n l))
```

---

*Caveat lector*: both of the above functions, unlike @Marimuthu's suggestion, will raise an exception if `n` is an out-of-bounds index. The exception comes from `!!`.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat emptor if you pick a bad index, but—

```
dupN n xs = let (first, x:rest) = splitAt (n-1) xs in first ++ x:x:rest
```

Comment: This is the prettiest one.  I'd like `in first ++ [x,x] ++ rest` even better, I think.

Comment: Thanks! I like your suggestion a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [splitAt](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asplitAt):

```
dupl n xs = first ++ take 1 rest ++ rest where (first, rest) = splitAt (n - 1) xs
```

This will not break if `n` is out of bounds.